# Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Web

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc-4, web-config

Trying to use a mysql db with a mvc4 project and ran into this error.

the error is triggering at my membershipprovider in web.config

```
 <membership defaultProvider="MySqlMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="MySqlMembershipProvider"
         type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLMembershipProvider,
     MySql.Web, Version=6.5.4.0, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"
     autogenerateschema="true"
     connectionStringName="MySqlConnectionString"
     enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
     enablePasswordReset="true"
     requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
     requiresUniqueEmail="false"
     passwordFormat="Hashed"
     maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"
     minRequiredPasswordLength="6"
     minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
     passwordAttemptWindow="10"
     passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""
     applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

i have MySql.Data, MySql.Data.Entity and MySql.Web in my referrences, all added with nuget install-Package commands. How can it still not be found ? Does it have something to do with not installing some MySql stuff directly on my machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out getting the references with NuGet got different versions.

MySql.Data and MySql.Data.Entity where of version 5.x.x.x, while MySql.web was of version 7.4.0

specifying the version, like so

```
Install-Package MySql.Data -Version 6.7.4
```

for both MySql.Data and MySql.Data.Entity made the site run without error.

installing MySql connector and referencing these 2 dll's from the 6.7.4 version also works.

Short answer, the issue originating from having different versions with these dll's, NOt because one of them were missing.

Answer (score 1):

Install MySQl Connector and add reference of that. That was helped me.

You can find the connector for MySQL from [Here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/)

Comment: It says that i already have a reference to MySql.web which makes sense since i got that reference when i installed the package with NuGet

Comment: have you added reference to the dll file ? and make sure the version mentioned here is the same as your referenced dll.

Comment: i had, it seems the issue wasn't missing references, but the references being to different version. I wasn't aware of this because i had gotten the references with NuGet Install-Pacakge commands

Comment: Worked for me too. Didn't even have to reload my project.